# PHP overloaded static property and static method

Tags: php, function, oop, properties, static

Situation: I have a class that has a static property, a static method and a few abstract elements that aren't too interesting right now. Here's my first class:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public static $property = 'Foo';

    public static function func()
    {
        echo self::$property

        ...
    }
}
```

Now the fun begins. I want to extend this class, overload the static property, use the same not overloaded method.

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public static $property = 'Bar';
}

Child::func(); //Output: 'Foo'
```

Thw problem is, I always get 'foo' (eg. the parent's default property value). What do I do wrong?

Comment: you aren't echoing the $property from the Child you are echoing the property from the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ParentClass` (since the word `Parent` is a reserved keyword) change...

```
echo self::$property;
```

...to this...

```
echo static::$property;
```